# Spark streaming error during job runtime in cluster (yarn resource manager)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, dstream

I am facing the following error:
I wrote an application which is based on Spark streaming (*Dstream*) to pull messages coming from PubSub. Unfortunately, I am facing errors during the execution of this job. Actually I am using a cluster composed of 4 nodes to execute the spark Job.

After 10 minutes of the job running without any specific error, I get the following error permanently:

> ERROR org.apache.spark.streaming.CheckpointWriter:
>   Could not submit checkpoint task to the thread pool executor  java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task   org.apache.spark.streaming.CheckpointWriter$CheckpointWriteHandler@68395dc9 rejected
>   from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1a1acc25
>   [Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 1000, completed tasks = 412]

Comment: Any update on this error?